# How to prevent my input jump to other function as the program continue

Tags: c++, c

My problem is when i input more than 1 number or characters(ex:156) the value 56 directly go to my next function ( f1, f2 ). How can i prevent that and print out that is an error ? (p.s : i'm new so if you guys can help me w/o using iostream, it'd be great

```
char c;
printf("menu");
printf("Please enter the option 1 - 4, press q to quit\n");
input_c:            
scanf("%c",&c);
do{         
switch (c)          
case '1': f1();
break;
case '2': f2();
break;
case 'q': quit();
break;
default: goto input_c;
break;
}
```

i edited this as my original code which lead me to the same problem

Comment: First, why are you declaring an array of 2 size (`c`) and then just use only one of its elements?
Second, using `goto` is not suggested often.

Answer (score 1):

In `char c[2];` declaration, `c` is a array of 2 characters ranging from index 0 to 1. So while reading the input into it, `scanf("%c", &c[i])` should be used.

You cannot use array index as 2 in statement `switch (c[2])`, since array indexing starts from `0` in `C`.

```
main() {
char c; 
scanf("%c", &c);
switch(c) {
   case '1': f1(); break;
   case '2': f2(); break;
   case 'q': quit(); break;
   default: //blah
}
```

The above method can be employed with simplicity.

Comment: this is my original code to write my menu, but since it keep jump to function f1 i try doing it w/ array (which give the same problem)

Answer (score 0):

The reason of this behavior is because you declared an array of chars [2] and you're only using one of its elements (first). So when you input 145, it takes the 1 only and that's why it goes to the first function.

Answer (score 0):

You're reading a character so, `strlen` on it is not correct and will make *undefined behavior*. Second, your array size is 2, so you can index it by 0 and 1. `c[2]` can invoke *undefined behavior* again.

Just use a simple character variable instead and replace `goto` by `while`:

```
char c;

while(true)
{
    scanf("%c",&c); // cin >> c;

    switch (c)
    {
    case '1':
        f1();
        break;
    case '2':
        f2();
        break;
    case 'q':
        quit();
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: i did all 3 things above but the problem is still remain.